# Simple R task: divide specified columns by 1000 at specified rows

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I have an OHLC array of stock quotes that I want to process.

```
             Open      High      Low        Close         Volume
2003-01-05   6111.01   6145.00   6102.70    6145.00         956
2003-01-08   6145.00   6190.00   5960.00    6135.05        8771
2003-01-09   6120.01   6250.00   6120.00    6225.00       10579
2003-01-10   6240.00   6285.00   6225.10    6261.00        8882
2003-01-13   6231.00   6325.00   6231.00    6270.00        8015
2003-01-14   6279.00   6295.00   6180.01    6190.00        8461
```

The company made a split @ given date, so I need to divide all open,high,low,close columns before that date by 1000.
As I am learning R basics now I want to figure out nice R solution for this task.
The best piece of code I've managed to code is (cant find out how to apply to given cols, stock$Open doesn't work):

```
apply(stock, 2, function(stock) stock/((index(stock)<"2007-07-20")*1000) )
```

However, the results are strange, many of them are inf:

```
2006-10-26       Inf       Inf       Inf        Inf         Inf
2006-10-27       Inf       Inf       Inf        Inf         Inf
2006-10-30       Inf       Inf       Inf        Inf         Inf
2006-10-31       Inf       Inf       Inf        Inf         Inf
2006-11-01       Inf       Inf       Inf        Inf         Inf
2006-11-02       Inf       Inf       Inf        Inf         Inf
2006-11-03       Inf       Inf       Inf        Inf         Inf
2006-11-07       Inf       Inf       Inf        Inf         Inf
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks everybody for help! My issue has been resolved 20 minutes after posting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `OHLC array`s, but assuming that index method works:

```
relevantRows<-index(stock) < "2007-07-20"
```

Once you've got a vector holding all the relevant rows (in fact a logical vector that holds TRUE for the rows that should be changed), you can probably use this simply like this:

```
stock$Open[relevantRows]<-stock$Open[relevantRows]/1000
```

It is possible (depending on the internals of `OHLC array`s), that even this works:

```
stock[relevantRows, c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close")]<-stock[relevantRows, c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close")]/1000
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick, your solution fits perfect for my needs! You saved me hours, maybe days of struggling! I owe you a beer, man. THANKS!!! R is beautiful language, but its hard sometimes to advance without advice.

Comment: Careful there, man: you just told a Belgian you owe him beer. But seriously: spend some time in the oft underestimated [Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf). All of the principles I used in my answer are present in that document. I know it got me very much on the right track and prepared for more advanced stuff!

Comment: Thanks again, @Nick, I'll definitely go through this guide. And I've found one more nice way to specify a date filter. Maybe it's not applicable everywhere, but works in my case (xts object)  `stock["::2007-07-19", c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close")]<-stock["::2007-07-19", c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close")]/splitRatio`

Answer (score 2):

If the date is not before 20/7/2007, then `(index(stock)<"2007-07-20")` is `FALSE` and so `(index(stock)<"2007-07-20")*1000` comes out as zero.  Your `Inf` values are a result of dividing by zero.

You could try this:

```
stock[index(stock) < "2007-07-20", -5] <- stock[index(stock) < "2007-07-20", -5] / 1000
```

Comment: Thanks @Pete for pointing me to that silly mistake, I really forgot I can't divide by zero :-0

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `adjRatios` function in the TTR package to do this.  It looks like you already have an xts object, so that's what I use:

```
library(quantmod)
x <- structure(c(6111.01, 6145, 6120.01, 6240, 6231, 6279, 6145, 6190, 
6250, 6285, 6325, 6295, 6102.7, 5960, 6120, 6225.1, 6231, 6180.01, 
6145, 6135.05, 6225, 6261, 6270, 6190, 956, 8771, 10579, 8882, 
8015, 8461), .Dim = c(6L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Open", 
"High", "Low", "Close", "Volume")), index = structure(c(1041746400, 
1042005600, 1042092000, 1042178400, 1042437600, 1042524000), tzone = "",
tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "")
s <- xts(1/1000,as.Date("2003-01-10"))
r <- adjRatios(s,,Cl(x))
OHLC(x) * drop(r[,"Split"]) * drop(r[,"Div"])
```

If you're using data from Yahoo Finance, then you can use the `adjustOHLC` function in quantmod to automatically pull split and dividend data from Yahoo and adjust the series.  See `?adjustOHLC` for more options.

Comment: Joshua, its data from russian stock provider finam.ru, I am using rusquant, its a quantmod based lib for fetching russian stocks data. I also playing with yahoo data, so will check adjustOHLC function, looks interesting for me. Thanks.